Edit: How many char does fgets consider from *stream, when passing to its char *str?
I have been sitting on this simple fundamental mistake for a while.
How do we avoid strings in the stdin, that are bigger than a defined sizeof(sring). Here sizeof(stdin_passed) >  sizeof(word_new). Furthermore we are restricted to the use of, ferror an/or feof.
Thanks in advanced
Edit:
Hint is, there is no \n character, i will try to work with it
Edit 2:
The Segmentation Error ocurred, because of a piece of code that was not shown. My fault.
Edit 3: We don't avoid anything. We take as much characters as allowed by char *str size. We are aware that char *str can end with '\n' or any char. This might be helpful, because strings end with the char '\0'.

int main() {

    char word_new[42];

    while(1) {
        /*help needed here: ouput is Segmentation Error*/

        if (fgets(word_new, sizeof(word_new), stdin) == NULL){
            // error occurs, thus use perror
            if(ferror(stdin)){
                perror("error occured in stdin");
                exit(1);
            }
            // no error and only EOF reached
            break;
        }

//not previously provided snippet:

char *wordpt = strchr(word_new, '\n');
*wordpt = '\0';

//no '\n' character => error



String longer than 40 characters will not have a '\n' as the last character. If it's 41 characters or longer, a '\0' will be placed at word_new[41] and the rest of the input will be read in the next iteration. if (strlen(word_new) == 41 && word_new[40] != '\n') // too long string

The code posted is incomplete. But generally the more idiomatic while(fgets(word_new, sizeof word_new, stdin) != NULL) is used, and then analyse why it failed after the loop.

I don't understand the question.  You read some data.  If there is more data available then you read it later.  Or you ignore it.  If you want to read all available data up until the first newline character, you read data until you see a newline.  If you have to dynamically allocate an array, then you do that.   If you want to do that with fgets, you need to write some logic.  Many implementations now include a getline function that does that for you.

Er, your title question and your code do not match up. Your question (and the text of your question) talk about input that is too long. Your code shows what happens when the input string is in a fail state or at EOF.

@plantpot,  Code cannot prevent a user from entering too much data.  Code can detect if too much data was entered.

Strings aren't 'in a fail state'. stdin might be, and you can test for that. Your question doesn't make sense.

You can quite easily check it yourself:
int main(void) 
{

    char word_new[5];
    int loopno = 0;
    char *result = word_new;

    while(result) 
    {
        /*help needed here: ouput is Segmentation Error*/

        if ((result = fgets(word_new, sizeof(word_new), stdin)))
        {
            printf("Loop no: %d\n", ++loopno);
            for(size_t index = 0; index < sizeof(word_new) && word_new[index]; index++)
            {
                printf("word_new[%zu] - '%s' Code: % 3hhd (0x%02hhx)\n", index, isprint(word_new[index]) ? (char [2]){word_new[index], 0} : "NP", word_new[index], word_new[index]);
            }
        }
    }
}

and the result for 1234567890 is self explanatory
Loop no: 1
word_new[0] - '1' Code:  49 (0x31)
word_new[1] - '2' Code:  50 (0x32)
word_new[2] - '3' Code:  51 (0x33)
word_new[3] - '4' Code:  52 (0x34)
Loop no: 2
word_new[0] - '5' Code:  53 (0x35)
word_new[1] - '6' Code:  54 (0x36)
word_new[2] - '7' Code:  55 (0x37)
word_new[3] - '8' Code:  56 (0x38)
Loop no: 3
word_new[0] - '9' Code:  57 (0x39)
word_new[1] - '0' Code:  48 (0x30)
word_new[2] - 'NP' Code:  10 (0x0a)

https://godbolt.org/z/9MYerPf67
I strongly recommend writing similar tiny programs at your stage if you do not understand something.

@chux-ReinstateMonica forgot to delete that part :)

You cannot avoid bad input. Your program can detect it and respond. Typically the most correct response is... terminate (with error message)!
Obtaining user input strings should typically look something like this:
// String space for input is reasonable, but not unlimited:
char s[100];

// Attempt to get input -- fail if not obtained
if (!fgets( s, sizeof(s), stdin )) complain_and_quit();

// Verify you got an entire line of input -- fail if not obtained
char * p = strpbrk( s, "\n\r" );
if (!p && !feof(stdin)) complain_and_quit();
if (p) *p = '\0';

// Now that I have a verified full line of input from the user, 
// I can do stuff with it, such as try to convert it to an integer, etc.
int value;
if (!convert_to_integer( s, &value )) complain_and_quit();

In other words, make your program require the input to be valid in order to succeed.

Minor: what if f in if (!p && !feof(f))?
